# Correlated Scalar SubQueries

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, correlated-subquery, scalar-subquery

I am using SparkSQL. I have the following table:

Department:

```
dep_id | emp_id | age
0 | 0 | 21
0 | 1 | 53
0 | 3 | 42
0 | 5 | 58
1 | 4 | 36
1 | 8 | 48
2 | 2 | 54
2 | 6 | 31
2 | 7 | 30
2 | 9 | 54
```

However, I am not being able to successfully execute the following query in SparkSQL:

```
SELECT   A.dep_id,
         A.emp_id,
         A.age,
         (SELECT  MAX(age) FROM department B WHERE A.dep_id = B.dep_id) max_age
FROM     department A
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Can anyone please help where I may be going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting an error? Which one?

Comment: You should store year of birth instead of age, because the age values tend to change all the time.

Comment: @GMB - the error is `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: Binding attribute, tree: max(age)#19163`

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a subquery, you can do this with window functions:

```
SELECT   dep_id,
         emp_id,
         age,
         MAX(age) OVER(PARTITION BY dep_id) max_age
FROM     department 
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Comment: I understand that this can be done with window functions. However, I need to be able to do the same with scalar correleated subqueries only.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare table `alias` :

```
SELECT A.dep_id, A.emp_id, A.age,
      (SELECT MAX(b.age) FROM department B WHERE A.dep_id = B.dep_id) max_age
FROM department A;
```

Comment: the query fails with the error - `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: Binding attribute, tree: max(age)#19163`